# How come the first letter in my final cout gets cut off?

Tags: c++

```
int main () {
    const int MAX_INPUT = 99;
    string names[MAX_INPUT];
    string eraseName;
    string newList;
    int numNames = 0;
    int i = 0;


    cout << "How many names do you want (max 99)? ";
    cin >> numNames;   

    do {
        if(numNames > MAX_INPUT) {
            cout << "Out of memory!" << endl;
            break;
        }  
        cout << "Enter name #" << (i+1) << ": ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,names[i]);
        ++i;
    }  
    while (i < numNames);

    cout << "What name do you want to eliminate? ";
    getline(cin,eraseName);
    cout << "Here is the list in reverse order, skipping ";
    cout << eraseName << "..." << endl;

    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numNames; ++i) {
        cout << names[i] << endl;
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

I have an assignment where I have to "eliminate" an element in an array and recreate the output. I know my final for loop will not erase the element, it's just there because I was testing the issue, but if names has two inputs (John Doe and Jane Doe) and I say to cout them the final loop couts:

John Doe
ane Doe

Comment: Why did you put `cin.ignore();` there?  Have you tried putting it somewhere else?

Comment: What happens if you enter 3 or more names? Which ones lose the first letter?

Comment: I dunno, but my 1st step would be figuring out what exactly `ignore` does, On a side note, better don't try to insert `-5` names.

Comment: I tried putting it after getline(cin,names[i]); but that creates an issue and I put it above cout << "Enter name #" << (i+1) << ": ";
and that created a spacing issue.

Comment: if I try 3 names the first name will be fine but the final two lose the first letter

Comment: are std::vector, std::sort and std::remove off of the table? You can improve your task using STL. About, the chomp letter, see if you can flush the cin buffer. I'm just a few ideas the came in my mind.

Comment: @ernie, can you explain what cin.ignore() does?

Comment: Using a debugger will help you narrow the scope of the failure.  Have you used the debugger?

Comment: @Captain Giraffe I'm sorry if this is wrong since I'm relatively new, but from my knowledge the typical "cin" alone would only take up until the first space in a user input, but using ignore allows cin to take in the input until the next enter occurs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following block of code

```
if(numNames > MAX_INPUT) {
   cout << "Out of memory!" << endl;
   break;
 }
```

does not need to be executed in every iteration of the `do-while` loop. You can change you function to use:

```
if(numNames > MAX_INPUT) {
   cout << "Out of memory!" << endl;
   // Deal with the problem. Exit??
}

do {
    cout << "Enter name #" << (i+1) << ": ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,names[i]);
    ++i;
}  while (i < numNames);
```

Once you move the check out of the loop, you have to ask yourself, "Do I need to ignore a character in each iteration of the loop?" The answer is "No". You need to ignore the newline only after reading `numNames`. So, you move it out of the loop also.

```
if(numNames > MAX_INPUT) {
   cout << "Out of memory!" << endl;
   // Deal with the problem. Exit??
}

// Ignore the newline left on the stream before reading names.
cin.ignore();

do {
    cout << "Enter name #" << (i+1) << ": ";
    getline(cin,names[i]);
    ++i;
}  while (i < numNames);
```

You can improve on that by making sure that everything up to and including the newline is ignored by using:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! this gave me a better understanding of what     cin.ignore  means which I think was my main issue here. My professor takes off points if we use anything we haven't learned yet, so I couldn't use the limits but it worked fine without them!

Answer (score 3):

Move `cin.ignore()` right after `cin >> numNames;`, before the loop that reads the names.

You only need this to ignore the newline that is left in the stream after reading the number of names. `getline()` reads (and ignores) the newline from the stream, so there's no need to call `ignore()` again before reading each name. As a result, it's reading and ignoring the first character of the name.